# Google Maps touch events not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ipad, google-maps-api-3

I'm running into an issue where touch events do not work, but click events do.

If you visit [Google's Javascript Events page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events), you'll notice that click events work and so do drag events. Now, in Chrome, use the device tool to change to an iPad. **Without refreshing,** try to drag and swipe around. It won't work. Normal click events will still work. Now refresh the page while in iPad device view. The touch events will work.

Our issue is that we're always stuck with the touch events not working, even on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are already two related Issues [#6425](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6425) and [#4599](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4599) reported in gmaps-api-issues.

And, based from the threads, these issues are not fully resolved yet. There are, however, given workarounds which you can also try and one is available in GitHub - [googleMapsAPITouchWorkaround](https://github.com/clshortfuse/googleMapsAPITouchWorkaround/blob/master/addTouchSupport.js).

For more of the workarounds, please go through the issues recorded in the tracker.